# What does the deterministicOverlappingPairs setting in PyBullet do?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, pybullet

It is not uncommon to find this line in PyBullet examples:

```
p.setPhysicsEngineParameter(deterministicOverlappingPairs=1)
```

What is the purpose of the "deterministicOverlappingPairs" setting? Why should I set it?

I have looked at the documentation and found out that this setting is related to collision detection. However, what exactly is happening under the hood was not explained in the [documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10sXEhzFRSnvFcl3XxNGhnD4N2SedqwdAvK3dsihxVUA/edit#).

A basic script that allows testing the setting by calling it with the "--dop" argument set to 0 or 1 is provided below. The argument is passed into the function on line 11:

```
import pybullet as p
import pybullet_data
import argparse
from datetime import datetime
numSteps = 500
numObjects = 50

def setupWorld(dop):
  p.resetSimulation()
  # The line I am interested in
  p.setPhysicsEngineParameter(deterministicOverlappingPairs=dop)
  p.loadURDF("plane.urdf")
  kukaId = p.loadURDF("kuka_iiwa/model_free_base.urdf", [0, 0, 10])
  for i in range(p.getNumJoints(kukaId)):
    p.setJointMotorControl2(kukaId, i, p.POSITION_CONTROL, force=0)
  for i in range(numObjects):
    cube = p.loadURDF("cube_small.urdf", [0, i * 0.02, (i + 1) * 0.2])
  p.stepSimulation()
  p.setGravity(0, 0, -10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Select run mode')
  parser.add_argument('--dop', metavar=1, type=int, 
                     help='Set value for deterministicOverlappingPairs')
  args = parser.parse_args()
  p.connect(p.GUI, options="--width=1024 --height=768")
  p.setAdditionalSearchPath(pybullet_data.getDataPath())
  
  start_time = datetime.now()
  setupWorld(args.dop)
  for i in range(numSteps):
    p.stepSimulation()
  print(f"Runtime = {datetime.now()-start_time}")
```

By running this script with the command line arguments "--dop 0" and "--dop 1", I did not notice a significant change in runtime.

Since, I do not know how *deterministicOverlappingPairs* is supposed to affect the simulation, I am unable to provide an example script that has a measurable output related to *deterministicOverlappingPairs*.

Comment: In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort.  Please provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: @itprorh66 I have updated my question and provided a minimal reproducible example. Since I am asking for help with a parameter that I do not understand, I struggle to further specify the question. I need help.